# What is the difference between Selenium & Selenium-wire in adding headers to Webdrivers?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, seleniumwire

I am using Selenium and Selenium-wire in Python. To amend headers in the webdriver, do we use request_intercept in Selenium-wire and ChromeOptions in Selenium?

***Example to change refers***
**Selenium-wire**

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def intercept(req):
    del request.headers['Refers']
    request.headers['Refers']='https://www.google.com/'
driver.request_interceptor= intercept

driver.get('URL')
```

**Selenium**

```
from selenium import webdriver

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

r='https://www.google.com/'
opt.add_argument(f'refers={r}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
```

Answer (score 2):

Selenium chromeoptions simply cannot do this. [Per the ChromeOptions documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities), the `options` does not include any functionality such as you've written in the second block of code.

I do believe that seleniumwire is the best way to accomplish this (it's designed exactly for this), and it's pretty simple. Do note that the `webdriver` import MUST be from selenium wire for this to work, as in your first example. Functionality from pure selenium must be imported specifically (eg `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`).

Selenium-wire does indeed have its own set of options, passed in something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)
```

but [even these do not include header modification](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#all-options).

So, I think your best bet is to continue using wire for request/response-specific actions and testing while adding from raw Selenium exactly what else you may desire.